# Drupal bootstrap theme

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, drupal, themes

I', using the latest Drupal 7 with Bootstrap theme. I have created a sub theme.
My problem is that if I ad blocks to highlighted or top bar regions all blocks content put verticaly aligned with a one homogene background. I would like to change this to put content to individualy blocks aligned horizontally.

Comment: `#page-header .well section {`
`min-height: 20px;`
`padding: 19px;`
`margin-bottom: 20px;`
`margin-right: 10px;`
`background-color: #f5f5f5;`
`border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;`
`border-radius: 4px;`
`-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);`
`box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.05);`
`display: inline-block;`
`width: auto;`
`max-width: 49%;`
`}`
`
This case almost what I want, but how can I use width: auto?? Becouse it works only if I add a max-width parameter.....

Comment: Can you show us some screenshot or jsfiddle with you problem?